# Is it a bad practice to have each method in a separate file?

Tags: c#

I made a `static partial class Utils` and I put each method in a separate file in the **Utils** folder.

But then looked up the partial classes and everywhere it says I shouldn't be using it except for separating auto-generated code.

So, should I merge it together or it's ok to have it in one folder?

Comment: *Why* did you put any methods in a separate file? And what do you mean "I put every method in a separate file"? That you created 10 files for 10 methods? Or 1 file with 5 methods and another with 5 more?

Comment: Why do you want it in seperate file? Do you do this normally with other classes as well?

Comment: Perhaps you need to figure out whether you can group together methods in `Utils` into their own static classes, and have one file for each **group** of methods.

Comment: This might be an indication that your methods are too long. You might consider splitting it into smaller methods. Of course, it then makes sense to put one public-facing method and all its private helper methods in one separate file.

Comment: If you have so many methods in one class, or methods so large that you store them in separate files you have a design problem. The class or the methods are too big and try to do too many different things.

Comment: Although the question might be considered off-topic as there is no definite answer, I have _never_ seen anybody using separate files for seperate methods except for automatically generated code which is then merged with manually written code.

Comment: I understand that any answers here will be opinion-based. But where/how am a programmer suppose to ask questions regarding _best practices_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all a `Utils` class with many methods tends to become a **huge pile of much unrelated code**. Because nearly all "Helper" methods will be placed there. By dividing them into single files you fight against a symptom and not againt the root cause. You'll transform the pile of code into a pile of files.

You should cluster the methods into topics and divide the Utils class in meaningful units. Please keep an eye on the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having one *class* per file makes a lot of sense as it is a self-contained unit.

If you are separating every method in to separate files you are introducing yourself to an organisational nightmare as methods within one class tend to be *related* and now instead of having a quick overview in a single file and being able to code easily, you've now spread yourself over many files.

You're doing nothing but shooting yourself in the foot.

EDIT: If you're worried about source-control (your question doesn't say anything about it - but I thought I'd add it), today's source-control systems are very good at merging, even if people are working on the same file.  There may be issues if two developers are working in the same locality (e.g. the same function) and a manual merge would be required, but in a well organised team - this is a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

> There are several situations when splitting a class definition is
>   desirable:
>
> - When working on large projects, spreading a class over separate files enables multiple programmers to work on it at the same time.
> - When working with automatically generated source, code can be added to the class without having to recreate the source file. Visual Studio
>     uses this approach when it creates Windows Forms, Web service wrapper
>     code, and so on. You can create code that uses these classes without
>     having to modify the file created by Visual Studio.
> - To split a class definition, use the partial keyword modifier, as shown here:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

With that said, I *rarely* see any reason why one would want to use `partial`. According to the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

> The single responsibility principle states that every module or class
>   should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality
>   provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class

Now one may argue that you're using the same class since you're using `partial`. However, *it is an indication* that you're doing to much in one class. Consider moving them into separate classes instead. I *personally* think that the gain from separating a util into several partial classes just moves the problem from a big class into a problem of several files. I believe that you will get more maintainable code if you follow the *Single Responsibility Principle*, and if you feel the need of splitting a class into several partial classes you're probably doing to much and are not following SRP.